# How to incorporate sub-categories and products into my database design

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, entity-relationship, mysql-workbench

I am having a difficult time in understanding how I can deal with properties in sub-categories (see Table) in my design. Specifically the PropInSubCatValue. The problem is that this field could be a decimal or varchar depending on the property. However when I define the field in Mysql, I am limited to choosing only one data type for this field.  Any ideas ? Thanks Jillian

[image]

Comment: Consider having one column per data type. It's not perfect, but it's probably the best you can do here. That's how wordpress do it. They seem to manage OK.

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry, you mean adding to the table properties_in_sub_categories fields like ProdInSubCatIntValue Int(11), ProdInSubCatStringValue VarChar(30), ProdInSubCatDecimalValue Decimal(9,2)..etc... where the non-used data types would be set to NULL when a new record is entered, which could mean quite a few NULLs in the table ?

Comment: Fair point. So, maybe have a different tables for each datatype. Have a look and see how wordpress (or joomla) do it.